# lookup dictionary value from a list (with comprehension)

Tags: python

If i have a list like:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

and a dictionary like:

```
my_dict = {'bob':1, 'jane':2, 'fred':17}
```

And i want to lookup the dictionary key,value using the list, i can do it this way:

```
In [69]: for i in my_list:
    ...:     for k,v in my_dict.items():
    ...:         if i == v:
    ...:             print(k,v)
```

which returns:

```
bob 1
jane 2
```

but i'm trying to work more with list and dict comprehension, and am struggling to figure out how to do this with comprehension... Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could filter `my_dict` by checking the values against `my_list` in a dict comprehension

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in my_dict.items() if v in my_list}
{'bob': 1, 'jane': 2}
```

but this is generating a new dict, not printing out elements (not sure what your eventual goal is)